# react native app crashes silently when adding realm db as a dependency

Tags: android, realm, react-native

I'm making a music app and I've come to the point where I implement the offline part of the app. For that, I decided to use RealmDB but after I added it as a dependency the app crashes on launch, silently. While testing, I created a new project from scratch and added Realm but everything was working fine, so it might be some kind of conflict between the dependencies. Literally, no logs are displayed and I've tried seeing android's logcat and nothing other than usual appears. **I don't know what information I should provide here** but I'll be updating it as it is requested.

Comment: Take a look at the following issue, it may help you. https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/2249

Comment: I tried that solution but now I'm getting a build error: `Conflicting configuration : 'armeabi-v7a,x86' in ndk abiFilters cannot be present when splits abi filters are set : x86_64,x86,armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a`

Comment: Figured that the build error I was getting was because of `enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture`. I've set it to false, but the app still crashes